# Facing Autoresizing Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autoresize

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEZSo.png)I am using Xcode 11 for this project which is fully used autoresizing. Now all screens become like this. Not getting what issue it is. It's working fine in Xcode 10.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the **2020**. Now start using auto-layout and size classes to create better UI.

Comment: It is not at all clear what the problem may be, as you have not shown how you think it *should* look vs how it *does* look. Please review [ask].

Comment: @DonMag the issue is my company is having old base which have been used autoresize. The thing is when I run the build on device which is having iOS 13 UI is becoming like this. Because of time constrain not going to Autolayout.

Comment: @Chan - ok... but still, you are not explaining what is "not right". Is the "dark" rectangle / view not stretching to fit the width? Can you show your auto-resizing settings? You say *"It's working fine in Xcode 10"* ... You are showing a design view -- are you sure you are designing with the same device size? Do the elements resize correctly at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

1.Try adding constrain again and works.

If point 1 does not work.

2. you can also set height of the view by calculating the total height of your content.